# Calculating the time taken by a program

Tags: c, time

Use the series tan{-­1}(x) = x – x3 / 3 + x5 / 5 – x7 / 7 + ... to calculate the value of pi. How fast is the convergence?
My attempt:

```
/* Calculating the value of pi */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// To calculate tan inverse
float CalculateInverseTan(float fX)
{
    float fY = 0;
    float fSign = 1;
    float fTerm = 0;
    int iii = 1;
    do
    {
        float fPow = 1;
        int jjj;
        // Calculating the power
        for (jjj = 1; jjj <= iii; jjj++)
        {
            fPow *= fX;
        }
        fTerm = fSign * (fPow / iii);
        fY += fTerm;
        iii += 2;
        fSign *= -1;
    } while (fTerm > 0.0001 || fTerm < -0.0001);
    return fY;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Let x = tan^(-1)(1).\n");
    time_t start = time(0);
    float fTanInverse1 = CalculateInverseTan(1);
    time_t end = time(0);
    printf("Therefore x = %f. Time of convergence = %f sec.\nAs x  = pi/4, therefore pi = 4x.\nTherefore pi = %f\n", fTanInverse1, difftime(start, end), 4 * fTanInverse1);
    return 0;
}
```

I have managed to calculate the value of pi. But the time of convergence is always coming as 0.

Comment: It is often useful when measuring the time of a particular process to run a significant number of iterations to produce a good average measurable time. Depending on the task, `10^6 - 10^9` iterations. E.g. `for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { your code }` and then either output the total or take the average.

Comment: @ln78 mark the correct answer and help others to find correct answer easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method.

```
#include <time.h>

int main() {
clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used;

start = clock();


… /* Do the work. */


end = clock();
cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: use printf("Time Consumed : %.3f sec", cpu_time_used); to print time

Answer (score 3):

Does it look like your program completes in < `1` second?

If that is the case, you will get a result of `0` because the `time` function has a resolution of only `1` second.

You could instead use the `clock` function which measures time in terms of ticks of your CPU, then you can convert it back to seconds.

[See here for usage and more information.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the cpu time
To get a process CPU time, you can also use the clock function. This is also declared in the header file `time.h'.
you can use a code like this,

`double cpu_time;

clock_t start = clock();

/* your function */

clock_t end = clock();

cpu_time = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`